# Why am I getting an error that file is missing on git checkout?

Tags: git, azure, visual-studio, azure-devops

I am trying to checkout a specific file from my remote master because when I previously pulled in all the new changes from master(via rebase), it deleted certain files from my local repo. I figured that for some reason those files were missing from the master, except they aren't and I  see them clear as day in the remote repo. Why does git not recognize those files exist?

The command:

```
git checkout origin/master FormFieldHistoryViewModel.cs
```

The error:

```
error: pathspec 'FormFieldHistoryViewModel.cs' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

I can see the file sitting there in the repo on Azure Devops. What is going on?

EDIT: sorry, should've mentioned I tried fetching and pulling before posting this.

Comment: This probably doesnt' need the [C#] tag

Comment: I'm guessing here that you didn't actually run `git fetch` at the right time, but another possibility is that you might need `git checkout origin/master -- FormFieldHistoryViewModel.cs`. I tested this with a recent Git and `git checkout` didn't need the explicit `--`, but there are some cases where you will occasionally need one; maybe older versions of Git have more.

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking you are seeing those files, but you don't have a local copy of them. You could try using `git fetch` before your `git checkout` command and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [@The2Step's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68896375/799379). (please select [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68896375/799379) as the accepted answer)

As we all know `git` is a distributed source control repo, you always have a complete local copy of the repo's history, and you need to operate with `pull` and `push` operations.

When you're viewing something in *Azure Devops* or a *GitHub* page, you are directly viewing the ***latest* remote** version of the code.

#### Simulation

Running the following code will simulate OP's state:

```
# run this if in PowerShell on windows, it will add a simple touch for
# the code below to work
# function touch([string]$Path){New-Item -ItemType File -Path $Path -Value ''}
mkdir git-playground; cd git-playground
mkdir origin; cd origin
git init -b master
touch first-file.txt
git add first-file.txt
git commit -m="first file committed"

cd ..; git clone origin local; cd origin
touch new-file.txt
git add new-file.txt
git commit -a -m="new file committed"

cd ../local
```

#### Reproduction

At this point you will be in the **local** directory, pointing to the `master` branch but with an older version of the repo.

Thus, running the following command:

```
git checkout origin/master new-file.txt
```

will producer the following error:

> error: pathspec 'new-file.txt' did not match any file(s) known to git

#### [@The2Step's Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68896375/799379)

I'm guessing OP doesn't want to `pull` at this time, and just wants to cherry-pick a file from the latest `origin/master` branch, and so you first step is to update the local repo with the necessary information from `origin`. That's done by running:

```
git fetch
```

output of this example scenario for me was:

```
git fetch                                                                                                                                                                remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (2/2), 229 bytes | 5.00 KiB/s, done.
From C:/_/Code/git-playground/origin
   bb77593..26b1794  master     -> origin/master
```

and run the cherry-pick checkout once more:

```
git checkout origin/master new-file.txt
```

which should now work out:

```
Updated 1 path from 550c46d
```

##### Some more details

Checking status

```
git status
```

will show that we are behind (because we never `pull`ed), and will show the new file we checked out as a change of the branch:

```
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   new-file.txt
```

---

### TIP: `fetch` is non-destructive

It is the step that makes the connection between the distributed copies of the repo. Always use it before operations with a `remote`.

Comment: I had fetched first. Still didn't work. What did work was hitting "show all files" in vs solution explorer. I saw the missing files in a dotted outline. I selected "include in project" and it worked. Do you know why I would've had to do that in the first place?

Comment: What you are describing sounds oddly specific to the Azure Devops, and my answer is from the git management side. I hope you find your answer.